# 0x Cannot post limit order on ropsten (404 error)

Tags: 0x

Endpoint - https://ropsten.api.0x.org/sra/v4/order doesn't work anymore (404 error).
Faced with this problem only on ropsten.
Mainnet works fine.

Did 0x change ropsten endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

The `/sra/v4` endpoints were renamed to `/orderbook/v1` some time ago, you can refer to https://0x.org/docs/api#post-orderbookv1order for updated docs

Comment: Was it renamed again? The orderbook/v1 endpoint stopped working for me a week ago, ie I cannot post any orders anymore, returning a 400 Bad Request error

Comment: No major changes to the orderbook, however, we are experiencing some ongoing issues with that API, please refer to https://status.0x.org/ for more info